# Crosswalk crashes: Use SharedXWalkView if you want to support shared mode

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I am using crosswalk with my cordova app.

I am experiencing the following error:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebView(CordovaActivity.java:340)
>   at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:376)
>   at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:368)
>   at de.gambify.android.CordovaApp.onCreate(CordovaApp.java:31) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Use
>   SharedXWalkView if you want to support shared mode at
>   org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.handleException(ReflectionHelper.java:233)
>   at
>   org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.handleException(ReflectionHelper.java:237)
>   at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.init(ReflectionHelper.java:132) at
>   org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.loadClass(ReflectionHelper.java:199)
>   at org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.java:112)
>   at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.(CordovaWebView.java:897)
>   ... 17 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Use SharedXWalkView
>   if you want to support shared mode ... 22 more

I thought at first it is related to the fact that I build my App only with ARM support. Now I have bundled my App with x86 as well as with ARM support, but still facing these errors.

What surprises me is the fact that it says I should use shared mode. I am currently using embedded mode.

The device I am seeing these issues is with a Samsung Galaxy S6 and Samsung Galaxy S6 edge.

I am using crosswalk 12.41.296.9

Answer (score 0):

You need add permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml, you can locate this file in this path platforms/android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml

Add this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

For me works deploying android-armv7-debug.apk

Comment: I have these permissions automatically added in my Cordova-based project (Ionic) but on Samsung S6, it seems to have a problem launching.

Comment: also on `asus - ASUS_T00J`